# PHP's pack/unpack in Go

Tags: go

I'm intending to rewrite a game server I already have working in PHP-cli.

As I cannot touch the client, I have to use the on-wire protocol as-is.  This is a pure binary format, with multiple fields per packet.  I use a modified version of PHP's pack/unpack commands to convert to and from this.  A packet is generally in the form:

#### header:

```
unpack('nitem/ncmdNum/NdataLen', $buf);
```

#### data:

any of several dozen subsequent unpack strings, as identified by cmdNum. e.g.:

- `a32first_name/a32second_name/a32third_name/nfirst_itemid/nfirst_flags/nfirst_level/nunused/Nfirst_perm_flags/Ncvsize/a{$cvsize}contentsVector`
- `nsuccess/ndummyfielda/a*xerror_msg/a*xtext/NcurrentVersion/NtimeLimit/a*xlimitValue/a*xlimit`

[Where `a{$cvsize}` means a fixed length string determined by the named (usually immediately previous) value, and a* means a zero-terminated variable-length string.. ]

The current PHP implementation unpacks this and calls the a function that deals with command 'cmdNum' passing an associative array containing the unpacked data. This in turn calls the sending code with a similar array for the return values.

Whilst I'm sure I could map these to structures, reading from the input (and writing to it) wouldn't simply be a matter of dropping the buffer over the struct.  Plus, most packet types are only used once, in a function dedicated to dealing with that message, so coding up several dozen structures, and the code to deal with loading each field individually, seems like a lot of work.

Is there any method or package that I can use as the basis for dealing with this sort of thing?  My searching for "php unpack in go" only seems to return results based on people unpacking a single numerical value, which is obviously easy enough to replace with encoding/binary!

The unpack/pack strings are auto-generated by some other PHP based on a specification grabbed from the client, so I could change that to create a different format fairly easily, if there is something I can use.  I'd normally have no issues with writing my own functions to do this sort of thing, but being totally new to Go, this might be too much off-the-bat.

Comment: Defining structs for the messages (or groups of similar messages) is the way to do it in Go. If those format strings are fixed (and not, say, computed at runtime), consider generating the Go types and parse functions (or at least the bulk of it).

Comment: Thank you ... the formats are fixed, so there should be no problem creating at least the basis of the structure code programatically.. It just feels un-elegant ...

Comment: Well, create a library. like `php-pack-go`. ;)